# A button on an Infopath form that Prints the form and Submits it, too

Tags: 2007, infopath, development

OK I've been asked to put a print button on an infopath 2007 form.

But they want me to amend the code so that the Click event submits the form to a Sharepoint 2007 Forms Library as well.

I know this requires code behind the form and full trust. But what is the code?

Everyone's telling me how easy this is. So how easy is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy. The problem with printing is that it calls an action on the client machine, and this is why it requires full trust. What you should really do is create a print view of the form and have the button switch from the  current view to the print view after the submit action, then give the user the instructions to press Ctrl+P or click the print button in the browser to actually print the form, this way they can select the proper printer and print the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what's your environment like but if your printer has email address you could email (submit) entire form to that address so it will be printed. This is probably too crazy but it will work without code :)

You can also submit to SharePoint and then create an [Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728093.aspx) to send it via email to printer.